# GitHub Archiving obsolete files

Tags: github

I have a GitHub repository with circa 30 files in it. Over time, 20 of them have become obsolete and I'm trying to find out what the way to archive them is.

Comment: Are the obsolete files still part of your working folder when you check out a recent branch or are they obsolete in the sense that you deleted them and you're wondering if you can archive them from older commits? Would you mind explaining more about what you want to accomplish? If they're still present but no longer needed, can't you delete them and commit that?

Comment: They're obsolete in the sense that I have them in my repository but no longer use so I would want to archive them to reduce the working files in my repo.

Comment: And deleting them and then committing that delete isn't enough? Wouldn't you want them to be part of history from when they were needed?

Comment: That may work, yes. However, are they going to disappear from everywhere if I do that or would I have a backup just in case?

Comment: Your backup would be the older commits where the files are still present.